# Translating simple Grep to Java

Tags: java, regex

When looking for

```
grep -aiH '^WARN\|^ERROR\|^FATAL' myLogFile.log | \
...
```

I wrote

```
if (!line.startsWith("ERROR") || !line.startsWith("WARN") 
           || !line.startsWith("FATAL")) {
...
```

But how would one take into account the "`i`" flag, making comparisons case indifferent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just convert line into an upperCase String first, with this method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()

So instead of `!line.startsWith(...)` write `!line.toUpperCase().startsWith(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Also might want to look at commons-lang StringUtils:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

For example `!StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(line, "ERROR")`

This has the benefit of being null-safe as well; if `line` is null, it will return false instead of throwing a NullPointerException.

finally - you could also try something like `!line.matches("(?i)(WARN|ERROR|FATAL).*")`